# Recreating BERT extract_features.py output with TensorFlow Hub model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub, bert-language-model

I produced a feature vector I am very happy with by cloning the BERT repo, downloading the "BERT-Base, Uncased" [pre-trained model](https://github.com/google-research/bert#pre-trained-models), and running [extract_features.py](https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/extract_features.py) like so:

```
PYTHONPATH=. python extract_features.py --input_file=~/sandbox/input.txt --output_file=~/sandbox/bert_output.jsonl --vocab_file=$BERT_BASE_DIR/vocab.txt --bert_config_file=$BERT_BASE_DIR/bert_config.json --init_checkpoint=$BERT_BASE_DIR/bert_model.ckpt --layers=-2 --max_seq_length=128 --batch_size=8
```

Note the `--layers=-2` arg, which specifies that I want the features from the second-to-last layer.

I am now trying to reproduce the same features using [this TensorFlow Hub model](https://tfhub.dev/google/bert_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1), which I believe to be the same model. I used [this hack](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/290) suggested on the TF Hub GitHub to access the desired layer, since only the output layer is exposed. The feature vector I get is suspiciously close, but not identical (individual floats are within about 1% of each other). I have confirmed that my input tokens are identical in both cases. Hoping someone with more knowledge of BERT configurations and internals can spot something obvious that I've overlooked, or suggest a way to proceed with debugging? I'm at a loss since the interfaces are pretty different.

Comment: Is your first approach using a BERT_BASE_DIR that points to model=bert_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12 ? Are you using the same max_seq_length in the two approaches?

Comment: Yes, the directory is named `uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12` and I downloaded the zip from https://storage.googleapis.com/bert_models/2018_10_18/uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12.zip. I'm think I'm using 128 as the max_seq_length in both cases; with the TF Hub model, I zero-pad the input arrays up to 128 since I'm testing with a short sentence.

Comment: Did you pad the inputs with [CLS] and [SEP] tokens?

Comment: Please do verify the tokens used by TF hub and extrac_features.py

Comment: I did add the [CLS] and [SEP] tokens to my input array, and confirmed that the outputs in both cases have two additional tokens compared to the words in my sentence. I also checked the index tokens against the vocab; everything seems to line up.